# PostgreSQL, Prevent alter materialized view changing WITH NO DATA to WITH DATA

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I would like to change the name of a PostgreSQL 10.1  materialized view without loosing the data. To refresh this materialized view takes more than 12 hours.

So in order to test the alter materialized view statement I tried it on a different materialized view that has the `WITH NO DATA` clause in its definition.

When I run the command:

```
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW etl.mv_test
RENAME to etl.vw_test
```

The `WITH NO DATA` clause has been changed to `WITH DATA`. So I assume the view will be refreshed. Is it possible to keep the `WITH NO DATA` clause in the altered view?

Comment: It still throws a "not populated" error after renaming (see [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w5NxaiwV8vgAh6n2KTHpxB/0)), which presumably means it hasn't been refreshed. You say the `WITH NO DATA` clause has changed; where are you looking exactly? Third-party admin tools (which includes pgAdmin) tend to miss some of these optional clauses when reconstructing DDL statements. Unless it came out of `pg_dump` or `psql`, I wouldn't trust it (and even then, it could be a bug).

Comment: I am using PGAdmin. After altering the view I open the CREATE SCRIPT and the WITH NO DATA has been changed

Comment: I'm guessing it's just a pgAdmin bug. The `CREATE` statement you're seeing doesn't come from Postgres, pgAdmin is builds it by inspecting the catalog tables, and it doesn't always get it right. Try defining your view as `SELECT 1/0`; you'll know exactly when it's being refreshed, because it'll throw a divide-by-zero error.

Comment: I think you're right! I tried the select 1/0 and it did not throw an error when altering the view name! Now going to try with a MV with data whilst changing the data in the MV source. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`WITH [ NO ] DATA` applies only to newly created materialized views. You can easily ignore what PgAdmin shows, because it does not matter for existing ones.

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html)

> WITH [ NO ] DATA
>
> This clause specifies whether or not the materialized view should be populated at creation time. If not, the materialized view will be flagged as unscannable and cannot be queried until REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW is used.

Comment: Additionally: that option is not even stored with the definition of the mview: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-matviews.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Isn't it in the `ispopulated` column?

Comment: @NickBarnes - no, `ispopulated` shows whether materialized view is currently populated. PgAdmin shows the option `WITH [ NO ] DATA` in case you are going to recreate the database/schema/view. In fact, this may be a bit misleading.

Comment: @klin: Doesn't `ispopulated=false` imply that the view was created (or refreshed) using the `WITH NO DATA` clause? Is there any other way to arrive at this state?

Comment: @NickBarnes - This is not a way to find out how the view was created, because `ispopulated` may be changed after `refresh`.

Comment: @NickBarnes: `refresh materialized view ... with no data`